# doxygen not launching help compiler

Tags: doxygen

I'm running doxygen 1.8.3 on Windows XP

My config file is setup to build help file

```
GENERATE_HTMLHELP      = YES
CHM_FILE               = ../../../Dist/Common/help/GTSDK/GTSDKL.chm
HHC_LOCATION           = "C:\Program Files\HTML Help Workshop\hhc.exe"
```

It has worked before, but the help file is no longer getting generated. I have not made any changes to the config file or the environment (as far as I'm aware). 
doxygen is not generating any errors. In fact it says "Running html help compiler..."
but hhc.exe is never executed. (I confirmed this with process monitor)
No errors are generated.

Any tips on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved my own problem CHM_FILE path was incorrect. too many "../"